# Cannot connect to one TFS, from one machine only

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I manage a TFS for our work place, it is hosted remotely (not by Microsoft, its our own instance). I can connect and login to this TFS from work fine. Other people from remote locations can connect also.

At home I work on projects too, I want to access my work TFS but when I try I encounter error as below.

[image: Error]

I can access the web portal fine at home, but Visual Studio doesn't want to connect. I'm not prompted for credentials. I have connected to this server before from home, but for unknown reasons it stopped.

I can connect to other TFS instances. I have two other TFS which I can connect too from home.

I've deleted the TFS cache, removed TFS reference in VS, reset VS settings completely, cleared windows credentials of any reference to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: The other TFS instances that you can connect to are on the same location as the one that is not working? Consider that you might need a VPN, maybe being on the same domain, maybe your IP is not whitelisted for that specific port, maybe your IP from home was whitelisted but you have a dynamic IP which changes frequently, maybe  your TFS instance doesn't support Basic authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- Disable your firewall(During the connection)
- Run VS 2015 in **admin mode**.
- Disable antivirus or add TFS in whitelist.
- [Clear VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).

You could also try to use the **IP address** instead of the link given by the TFS (`http://"ip address":8080/tfs` instead of `http://"link":8080/tfs`).
Or just follow the suggestion in the comment: using a VPN connection to the TFS server as a workaround.

Comment: Clear VS cache did it.